# Remap alt-tab to behave like win-tab

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, remapping, alt-tab

Just a quick one I hope -- is there any way in Windows to make alt-tab behave like win-tab? I've poked and googled and not found anything, so assuming there isn't ... but if anyone knows of a way, that'd be fantastic.

I'm suspecting the answer is nay and external software like AutoHotkey required to do the mapping instead.

Comment: Yes, I believe external software is required - it's a lot more difficult to change default keyboard shortcuts in Windows than it is in most GNU/Linux distributions - I've been using Windows as my main OS for years and don't think it's possible, and I just started looking into GNU/Linux and know how already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-386639.html#386639 and x79animal's solution:

```
$*Tab:: 
Getkeystate, Laltstate, Lalt, P 
if Laltstate = D 
Send {LAlt up}{LWin down}{Tab} 
else 
Send {Tab} 
return 

~$*LAlt up::Send {Lwin up}
```

Worked for me!
PHew

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotKey is going to be your best and easiest bet.

Comment: You'll want to check this page out - http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes (at least on XP, I can't test on Vista or 7, although I'd be interested to know if this works before I upgrade)

I wanted the opposite of your request i.e. Win-Tab (aka Cmd-Tab) to function as Alt-Tab. Phoshi's answer doesn't work for me, so I've added what does and also how to do what you originally asked

> make alt-tab behave like win-tab

Here you go:

```
LAlt & Tab::Send #{Tab} ; this will make Alt-Tab function as Win-Tab
```

And the opposite:

```
LWin & Tab::AltTab ; this will make Win-Tab function as Alt-Tab
```

I haven't worked out ShiftAltTab or Shift*Win*Tab yet, but I don't use them as I tend to only switch between the current and last app in this way. I use Launchy on Windows and QuickSilver on the Mac for switching between many applications.

Comment: That kinda works. But it's unpredictable. I either get flip-3d properly, flip-3d briefly (i.e., I press alt-tab, it gives me a quick glimpse of flip-3d before giving me back my desktop); the standard alt-tab with the preview windows or the classic alt-tab which gives you the app icons (a la WinXP).

So - close, but no cigar I'm afraid :-/